# How to redirect a user if it is superuser one site and if another is active? After login Page not found (404)

Tags: python, django

do you know how to do this function? I used LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL but now I have two types of users and the two in different views how to redirect them to the corresponding view? Thanks in advance!

And I deal with this way in the view:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import login

def my_login(request, user):
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        #your logic here
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/solicitar/home/')
    if request.user.is_active:
        #your logic here
        return redirect("/dashboard/")# or your url name
```

and url global:

```
urlpatterns = [
 # Examples:
url(r'^solicitar/', include(urls, namespace="usuario")),

url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^grappelli /',include('grappelli.urls')),
url(r'^grappelli /',include('grappelli.urls')),
url(r'^$', my_login, {'template_name':'login.html'}, name="login"),
url(r'^logout/', logout_then_login, name="logout"),
```

But I throw the error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://sgi-hrr.herokuapp.com/accounts/profile
```

I should redirect myself to the 'home'.

my template **login.html**:

```
...
<img src="">
<form method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="username">Usuario:</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username" 
    required>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>    
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="username">Contraseña:</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" required>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Ingresar">
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Help me please! Thanks in advance...

Comment: /accounts/profile is a default LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL in Django, please add  your own url  in settings.py

Answer (score -1):

try it, it should work

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import login
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def my_login(request, user):
 if request.user.is_superuser:
    #your logic here
     return redirect('/solicitar/home/')
 if request.user.is_active:
    #your logic here
    return redirect("/dashboard/")
```

also add your default `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` in settings.py

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = /solicitar/home/
```